# Panning the map changes gesture recognizer behavior?

Tags: ios, skmaps

So, I have a custom gesture recognizer added to a skmap, but the behavior is not consistent but rather weird. At first, both map and my gesture recognizer respond to gesture events.

But after panning or pinch to rotate & zoom, only gesture recognizer responds to gestures. While map does not respond to any gesture like pinch/panning/tap. This I call it a "locked" state.

In this state, map does not respond to anything. Trying to rotate/pinch will "unlock" it. But trying to pan will not. So for example, the sequence is, I pan the map, it follows. Then I pan the map several times, it does not move at all. Then I try to rotate it, the map stays still. Then I pan it the third time, it can follow my gesture again.

So my question is, what is the difference between this two state, what changes happened to the map when I move/try to rotate it.

My code is very simple, just for test purpose. myGestureRecognizer.m :

```
#import "myGestureRecognizer.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@implementation myGestureRecogniczer
-(id)init;
{
    self = [super init];
    self.delegate = self;
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Touches Began");
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Touches Moved");
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Touches Canceled");
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Touches Ended");
}
@end
```

And mapViewController.m :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myMapView = [[SKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f,  CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame))];
    self.myMapView.delegate = self;
    self.myMapView.calloutView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.myMapView];

    myGestureRecogniczer *gestureRecognizer = [[myGestureRecogniczer alloc] init];
    [self.myMapView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}
```

Comment: In addition, apple's mkmap does not have this problem. So I guess the question is, anyone has any idea how is skmap implemented to handle gestures.

Comment: We're looking into it

Comment: Our developers looked into it and the first question is: why do you need to add your own gestures? Doing this would interfere with the logic we've implemented and might lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Ando Hi Ando, I wanted to let user draw lines on map with single tap pan gesture.